# Are there pre-installed .png image samples in Windows standard installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, images

There are pre-installed `.jpg` image samples available in the user-independent directory of `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures` in Windows 7 with a standard installation.

Are there image samples available similarly but in the `.png` format in the standard install as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there image samples available similarly but in .png format in the standard install as well?

By default, there are only .jpg images installed to that Public profile directory, you could make your own image which contained .png files if you wanted.